# Django doesn't render images

Tags: python, django

[WebSite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isf7t.png)
[Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3WLf.png) 
First of all sorry for bad english. But i cant see my images on my website. I can see titles descriptions. Can you help me. I checked page resources it links my images and there is no problem.
thats exactly where my photos are
[page resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3chVd.png)

```
settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
template

 <ul class="slides-container">
            {% for rs in sliderdata %}
            <li class="text-center">
                <img src="{{ rs.image.url }}" alt="">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h1 class="m-b-20"><strong>Hoşgeldiniz <br> Site İsmi</strong></h1>
                            <p class="m-b-40">{{ rs.title}} <br> {{ rs.description }}</p>
                            <p><a class="btn hvr-hover" href="#">İncele</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
views.py

def index(request):
    setting = Setting.objects.get(pk=1)
    sliderdata = Slider.objects.all()[:3]
    category = Category.objects.all()
    context={'setting':setting, 'page': 'home','category':category,'sliderdata':sliderdata}
models.py 

class Slider(models.Model):



        Status = (
            ('True', 'Evet'),
            ('False', 'Hayır'),
        )
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        description=models.CharField(max_length=255)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
        create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Comment: Is the image available on `images` folder?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you added your images not in your templates. You should add

```
<img src="{{ rs.image.url }}">
```

Comment: i uploaded them on my template. Aha Türkmüşsün kardeşim şöyle özetliyim. Admin e slider isimli bir kategori oluşturdum buraya foto isim ve açıklama ekleyerek sliderımı oluşturmayı planlıyordum. title ve desc siteye geliyor ancak foto gelmiyor sayfa kaynagını inceliyorum fotoların upload edildiği yeri gösteriyor ancak yol düzgün olmasına rağmen site de fotoyu göremiyorum

Comment: if it worked please mark my solution as valid by clicking on the tik.

Comment: Yukarıda yazdığım kodu html'e eklediğinde çalışması gerekir ayırca ingilizce yazman gerekir ki insanlar anlasın.(en) You should add the code above to your template and it should work.

Comment: İ ve already added that code to my html you can see it on codes that i shared

Comment: try it on a blank template  maybe it is on the background. I mean on a html file where no additional content is there, only the photo and the text.

Comment: and also have you an uploads folder and can you see your photos after you uploaded them in your folder.

Comment: whenever i see that suggest i tried still only title description no image. Thanks btw all advices. Can you reach me from my email i can show you all project file. Maybe that makes sense. Sorry for bad eng

Comment: ive just seen your other message. Yes i got a folder is name upload and all images that i upload stored there automatically